# Unable to cast the Object to Entity Type

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, redis

I am trying to use Redis Cache to improve the performance of our application. I am referring this [article](https://kumarshivam-66534.medium.com/implementation-of-spring-boot-data-redis-for-caching-in-my-application-218d02c31191) for my implementation. I am getting this exception:

```
class com.entity.UserEntity cannot be cast to class com.entity.UserEntity
```

RedisConfig:

```
@Configuration
@EnableCaching
public class RedisConfig {

    @Value("${spring.redis.port}") int redisPort;
    @Value("${spring.redis.host}") String redisHost;

    @Bean
    public LettuceConnectionFactory redisLettuceConnectionFactory() {
        RedisStandaloneConfiguration redisStandaloneConfiguration = new RedisStandaloneConfiguration(redisHost,redisPort);
        return new LettuceConnectionFactory(redisStandaloneConfiguration);
    }

    @Bean
    public RedisTemplate<String, Object> redisTemplate() {
        RedisTemplate<String, Object> redisTemplate = new RedisTemplate<>();
        redisTemplate.setConnectionFactory(redisLettuceConnectionFactory());

        redisTemplate.setKeySerializer(new StringRedisSerializer());
        redisTemplate.setHashKeySerializer(new StringRedisSerializer());
        redisTemplate.setHashKeySerializer(new JdkSerializationRedisSerializer());
        redisTemplate.setValueSerializer(new JdkSerializationRedisSerializer());
        redisTemplate.setEnableTransactionSupport(true);
        redisTemplate.afterPropertiesSet();
        return redisTemplate;
    }
}
```

User Entity:

```
@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper=false)
@Slf4j
@Table(name="user")
public class UserEntity extends BaseEntity implements Serializable {
    
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "user_id")
    @Type(type = "uuid-char")
    private UUID userId;//Binary in DB and UUID here

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "user", orphanRemoval = true, cascade= CascadeType.ALL)
    @JsonIgnore
    @ToStringExclude
    @Fetch(value = FetchMode.SUBSELECT)
    private List<EmailAddress> emailAddresses = new ArrayList<>();
   .
   .
   .
}
```

UserDaoImpl

```
@Repository
public class UserDaoImpl implements UserDao {

    private UserRepository userRepository;
    private HashOperations hashOperations; //to access Redis cache
    private static final String KEY = "User";

    public UserDaoImpl(@Autowired RedisTemplate<String, Object> redisTemplate, @Autowired UserRepository userRepository) {
        this.userRepository = userRepository;
        hashOperations = redisTemplate.opsForHash();
    }

    @Override
    public Optional<UserEntity> fetchUserById(String userId) throws Exception {
        
// Getting Exception here (UserEntity) hashOperations.get(KEY,userId)
        UserEntity userEntity = (UserEntity) hashOperations.get(KEY,userId);
        Optional<UserEntity> userOptional = Optional.ofNullable(userEntity);
        if(!userOptional.isPresent()) {
            userOptional = userRepository.findByUserId(userId);
            if (userOptional.isPresent()) {
                System.out.println("Cache Miss User id:" + userOptional.get().getUserId());
                
                hashOperations.put(KEY, userOptional.get().getUserId().toString(), userOptional.get());
            } else {
                throw new Exception("User not present");
            }
        }
        return userOptional;
    }
}
```

I am successfully able to put UserEntity in the Cache, but then on retrieval I get the exception mentioned above. Most likely, the issue is because of Hibernate. When we cache the entity first time it puts Proxy/PersistentBag in place of Collections, so next time (in some other session) when we retrieve the Object back from Cache we are unable to cast it to the required entity. Can someone confirm that this is the issue, if yes, how to resolve it?

Answer (score 0):

Hibernate decorates the class, which is probably causing the problem, plus there are heavyweight references to the underlying database.

I strongly recommend (whether you're using Redis or not) defining a [POJO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pojo) version of your entity and converting the entity class into the POJO as *early* as possible, and converting the POJO to the entity as *late* as possible, so your application deals with POJOs, and receives, validates and emits (from its API) POJOs, and the entity is *only* used when interacting with the database.

Store POJO instances in Redis instead of entity instances.

Or to be more robust, serialise your POJO to json and store the json string in redis, deserialising it on the way back. Jackson (which come for free with spring boot, supports this out of the box. It's super simple to implement, *plus* you can easily debug content in Redis by visual inspection of its content.

Comment: Hi Bohemian, I am also facing same issue as above and also tried POJO class but same error. Can you suggest some more ideas?

Comment: @Aks1316 You can't cast entity objects. You must serialise them or manually map them to a POJO

Comment: I am not casting Entity to POGO. I am converting Entity to POGO manually using setter/getter then storing that POGO to redis and then using get operation and trying to set data in same POGO still I am getting error. 
class com.dto.UserDto cannot be cast to class com.dto.UserDto

Comment: @Aks1316 could be a class loader problem. Debug and see if the class of the POJO is `==` the target class. If not (likely) make sure the target class is loaded by the same class loader as what's retrieved from Redis. If that's too hard/awkward, use reflection to get the field values from the object and copy over the values to an instance of your target class. Alternatively, don't store objects in Redis; instead serialise to json and store json strings in redis, which is what I do because json is more durable to changes in the class.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution of this problem. I was making mistake. The only answer I found was this Hibernate decorated entity is causing issue.
It is not at all related to Hibernate.
While we create redisTemplate we also adding key and value serialization.
I was adding wrong seriazation.

```
    redisTemplate.setKeySerializer(new StringRedisSerializer());
    redisTemplate.setHashKeySerializer(new StringRedisSerializer()) 
    redisTemplate.setHashKeySerializer(newJdkSerializationRedisSerializer());
    redisTemplate.setValueSerializer(new JdkSerializationRedisSerializer());
```

By Default seriazation is JDK and which is required. I was not using that and adding StringSeriazation so data was stored in String format in REDIS. So when we perform deserization we need to implement deserializer.

For more details of Serialization refer below link
https://medium.com/@betul5634/redis-serialization-with-spring-redis-data-lettuce-codec-1a1d2bc73d26